My recipe.html file is rendering as both home page and recipes page on server
In my project im trying to render index.html as my home page and recipes.html to render on /recipes. Currently recipes.html is rendering on both my home page and /recipes page.
I have tried changing the URL patterns and added a new view to views.py.
workspace/recipe2/wrd/views.py
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic import ListView, TemplateView, View
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Recipe


class IndexView(View):
    
    def get(self, request):
        """ get request """
        recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(status=1)
        context = {
            "recipes": recipes,
        }
        return render(request, 'recipe.html', context)

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')       






workspace/recipe2/wrd/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='recipes-index'), 
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    
      
]

workspace/recipe2/recipes/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='recipes-index'), 
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    
      
]

